# Rails around_action in the callback stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just discovered around_action callbacks. I don't really understand how those callbacks work with the rest, and especially how the call stack looks like compared to using `(append_)before_action` or `prepend_before` callbacks. Would the around action callback be good for an access control like this :

```
ApplicationController < ...

  around_action :access_control

  private

  def access_control
  if @authorized
    yield
  else
    # Show error page
  end
end

class AdminController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authorize_admins

  private

  def authorize_admins
    if current_user.admin?
      @authorizez = true
    end
  end
```

Does around_action behave like an `append_before_action` + `prepend_after_action` or `prepend_before_action` + `append_after_action` ?

Or something different ?

Comment: `append_` and `prepend_` are a little different things. I would not view the problem  in this context. In fact, your question does not make sence. around_action behaves like before_action + after_action putting into the same place.     (`before(after)_filter` is the same as `before(after)_action` in Rails 4)

Comment: @chumakoff I had understood that `append_before_action` was an alias for `before_action` and same for after_action ? I am rewriting everything with  `action` and `callback` for more clarity

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`around_action` are more like `append_before_action` + `prepend_after_action`.

Internally, think of it like `rails` has two arrays, `@before_actions` and `@after_actions`. So when you declare `around_action`, it pushes/appends it to the end of `@before_actions` and it unshift/prepends to the `@after_actions`.

With a quick test as follows:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :before_action
  after_action :after_action
  around_filter :around_action

  def before_action
    $stderr.puts "From before_action"
  end

  def after_action
    $stderr.puts "From after_action"
  end

  def around_action
    begin
      $stderr.puts "From around_action before yielding"
      yield
      $stderr.puts "From around_action after yielding"
    end
  end

  def index
  end
end
```

I got the following in the log:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-21 17:11:01 -0700
Processing by SomeController#index as HTML
From before_action
From around_action before yielding
  Rendered some/index.html.slim within layouts/index (1.5ms)
From around_action after yielding
From after_action
```

Comment: Do you mean that if a controller would have the following filters:  `after_action :action1`; `around_action :action2` then `action2` would finish before `action1` ?

Comment: Yes, please see the sample code and output in the update.

Comment: Your right, man ! It's like `around_` callbacks in ActiveRecord.

Comment: Then consider it answered.